# What's the proper way to use sockets in goroutines

Tags: sockets, go, concurrency, goroutine

Im reading different things about sockets in Go lang. Can it be used in 2 goroutines for reading and writing without any concurrency control?

Im showing the code below, but I also failed using channels.

I basically created a small app to intercept the communication protocol of a certain application and I'm replacing a few bytes from the server before it hits the client in my pc.

for that I have 2 go routines:

One reading the socket from the server, replacing some bytes and sending to the client.

The other is reading the socket from the client and sending to the server.

it works fine for a few messages an then crashes.
This is my code and console output:

***Note:A similar implementation in python works fine.

```
    package main

    import (
        "fmt"
        "net"
        "sync"
        "log"
    )

    func main() {

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(2)

    server := StartShard()
    client := StartClient()

    go func() {
        ShardToClient(client, server)
        wg.Done()
    }()

    go func() {
        ClientToShard(client, server)
        wg.Done()
    }()

    wg.Wait()

}

func StartClient() (net.Conn){

    servAddr := "server1.gamek.io:2593"
    tcpAddr, err := net.ResolveTCPAddr("tcp4", servAddr)
    checkError(err)
    conn, err := net.DialTCP("tcp", nil, tcpAddr)
    checkError(err)

    return conn
}

func StartShard() (net.Conn){

    service := "localhost:2593"
    tcpAddr, err := net.ResolveTCPAddr("tcp4", service)
    checkError(err)
    listener, err := net.ListenTCP("tcp", tcpAddr)
    checkError(err)
    conn, err := listener.Accept()
    checkError(err)

    return conn
}


func ShardToClient( client net.Conn, server net.Conn  ){

    var buf = make([]byte, 1024)
    var bufRead int
    var err error

    for {
        bufRead, err = client.Read(buf)
        checkError(err)

        if bufRead > 0 {
            if buf[0] == 0x8C{
                fmt.Println("AVOIDING REDIRECTION ...")
                buf[1] = 127;
                buf[2] = 0;
                buf[3] = 0;
                buf[4] = 1;
            }
            fmt.Printf("ShardToClient(%d): %X\n", bufRead, buf[0:bufRead])
            bufRead, _ = server.Write(buf[0:bufRead])

        }
    }
}

func ClientToShard( client net.Conn, server net.Conn  ){

    var buf = make([]byte, 1024)
    var bufRead int
    var err error

    for {
        bufRead, err = server.Read(buf)
        checkError(err)

        if bufRead > 0 {
            fmt.Printf("ClientToShard(%d): %X\n", bufRead, buf[0:bufRead])
            bufRead, err = client.Write(buf[0:bufRead])
            checkError(err)
        }
    }

}

func checkError(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("fatal: %s", err)
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

> ClientToShard(66): 0E00A8C08067616270000000073776F720000000FF
>
> ShardToClient(3): BD0003
>
> ClientToShard(11): BD000B352E302E392E3000
>
> ShardToClient(46):
>
> A8002EFF000100015468652046690D0F723
>
> ClientToShard(3): A00001
>
> AVOIDING REDIRECTION ...
>
> ShardToClient(11): 8C7F0000010A214C8D6573
>
> 2019/01/12 14:32:45 FATAL: EOF

Answer (score 1):

The application handles all errors from network operations by calling `log.Fatal`.  The log.Fatal function exits the process.

The log line

```
2019/01/12 14:32:45 FATAL: EOF
```

indicates that a peer closed a network connection. The application handled this error by exiting.

The application should handle network errors by cleaning up any resources and exiting the goroutine.  For example:

```
func ClientToShard( client net.Conn, server net.Conn  ){
    defer client.Close() // close network connections on return from this function
    defer server.Close()

    var buf = make([]byte, 1024)
    var bufRead int
    var err error

    for {
        bufRead, err = server.Read(buf)
        if err != nil {
            return
        }

        if bufRead > 0 {
            fmt.Printf("ClientToShard(%d): %X\n", bufRead, buf[0:bufRead])
            bufRead, err = client.Write(buf[0:bufRead])
            if err != nil {
                return
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Make a similar change to ShardToClient.

Bonus comment: Replace the core of `ClientToShard` with a call to [io.Copy](https://godoc.org/io#Copy).

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation of net.Conn](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#Conn) says:

> Multiple goroutines may invoke methods on a Conn simultaneously.

So I suspect this is not the issue per se, but rather you have a bug in your code.

It is difficult to debug your code without setting up your env with the shard and client etc., but I just want to point out that concurrent access to `Conn` is not the problem. Try to instrument the client read more - is there any data read with the EOF?